# OpenERP - ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: project.group_project_manager

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am new to OpenERP. I am getting this error while installing ***Project Management Module***.
am not able to find where it went wrong.
Here is the error log:`

> K-SOFT ERP Server Error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1083, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1071, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 43, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 31, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 104, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 90, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 295, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 614, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 198, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 425, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 476, in _button_immediate_function
    _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 214, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 347, in load_modules
    processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 258, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 189, in load_module_graph
    load_update_xml(module_name, idref, mode)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    load_update_xml = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='update_xml')   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 126, in _load_data
    tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 954, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 847, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 652, in _tag_menuitem
    group_id = self.id_get(cr, group)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 824, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(cr, id_str)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 833, in model_id_get
    return model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, self.uid, mod, id_str)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 865, in get_object_reference
    data_id = self._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20130301_002301-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 858, in _get_id
    raise ValueError('No such external ID currently defined in the system: %s.%s' % (module, xml_id)) ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: project.group_project_manager
```

Can I have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Does any customised code is there in your addons or just base code is there?

Comment: Add dependency to `project` module in `__manifest__.py` of your custom module.